# ratio of 3 numbers with a given a number

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, ratio

My sister has a homework but I cannot understand the question correctly (do not know if it is correct as well)

> 3 numbers are in the ratio of "3:4:5". 28 is the middle number, what are the other 2 numbers

If I will solve the problem what I'm going to do is to create this equation

$\frac{3}{4} = \frac{x}{28}$

$x = 28 \times \frac{3}{4}$

$x = 21$

and 3rd number will be `35`. Is this the correct solution?

Comment: What don't you check if $\frac{28}{35}=\frac{4}{5}$?

Comment: Yes, correct. I imagine it as $$3k:4k:5k,$$ where $4k=28$, so $k=7$ etc.

Comment: thanks, your method is more elegant

Comment: Another approach is to put them in proportional form... $3+4+5=12$ so $\displaystyle 3:4:5\equiv \frac{3}{12}:\frac{4}{12}:\frac{5}{12} \equiv \frac{1}{4}:\frac{1}{3}:\frac{5}{12}$ so $28\equiv \frac{1}{3}$ so the whole is $84$ and $\displaystyle\frac{1}{4}\equiv 21$ and $\displaystyle\frac{5}{12}\equiv 35$.

Answer (score 0):

$28$ corresponds to the middle number in the ratio $3:4:5$

This implies that $1$ corresponds to $\frac{28}{4}$

The first number would therefore be $\frac{28}{4} \times 3$ , you can the same method to discover the third number.